# How to exit from a "window.after" loop?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I'm trying to understand how to exit from a "loop", I made this code in Tkinter just to understand, when i press `start` the loop begins and it repeats the 3 prints every 1 second. Is it possible to exit from the `start` loop pressing the `stop` button in some way?

```
from tkinter import *
cycle = True
def start():
    if cycle == True:
        print("1")
        window.after(1000,start)
    cycle = True
def stop():
    global cycle
    cycle = False
window = Tk()
window.geometry("200x200")
button1 = Button(window,text="Start",command=start)
button1.pack()
button2 = Button(window,text="Stop",command=stop)
button2.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is not a loop. its a recursive function. and it has no exit conditions. In this case you can try to set variable and check it in the start() function i.e `if run:` and change that var to false in the stop method.

Comment: Hi @BendikKnapstad, ok i edited my original code now i use a sort of mechanism, the first time works but if i click start for the second time obviously it doesn't work because the variable "cycle" is still false because i press stop, how to make it "true" when i press start again? Can you help me?

Comment: Ok @BendikKnapstad i think i found the solution, i added cycle = True just after the "if", so if i press stop cycle becomes false, and the program skips the if and cycle becomes true, so if i press again start the "loop" starts again, it's not a proper loop but it acts like an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding an extra function and calling the function before mainloop().

```
from tkinter import *


cycle = True

def print_text():
   if cycle:
      print("Hello World")
   window.after(1000, print_text)

   
def start():
    global cycle
    cycle = True

    
def stop():
    global cycle
    cycle = False

    
window = Tk()
window.geometry("200x200")
button1 = Button(window,text="Start",command=start)
button1.pack()
button2 = Button(window,text="Stop",command=stop)
button2.pack()

window.after(1000, print_text)

window.mainloop()
```